# Boto Python library still thinks it is in original EC2 datacentre after migration to another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, boto

I have migrated (actually copied) a Debian Amazon EC2 server from North Virginia to the Ireland datacentre, within a VPC.

I have been using [this python script](http://aws-musings.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/manage_snapshots1.txt) to make automated EBS snapshot backups very night, but since I have migrated the server, it doesn't work.

The new volume is not recognised as existing, but it can make a snapshot of the old volume in North Virginia, even though the server is in Ireland.

I get this error:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-100:~# python /srv/bin/manage_snapshots.py vol-fac935ae 14 "Test Backup"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/bin/manage_snapshots.py", line 36, in <module>
    volumes = conn.get_all_volumes([vol_id])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 2099, in get_all_volumes
    [('item', Volume)], verb='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1131, in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidVolume.NotFound</Code><Message>The volume 'vol-fac935ae' does not exist.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>30ba36b6-2f07-4c5f-b307-36865cb7ef44</RequestID></Response>
```

Assuming the problem is in boto configuration, how can I tell it that the server is now in Ireland?

I already have this in `~/.profile`:

```
# set AWS region
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

But I think that is only for the command line ec2-api-tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boto is using `us-east-1` region by default, that't why it was working fine until the migration.

For any other region, you have to update your boto.config file to explicitly set the region.

```
[Boto]
ec2_version = 2012-12-01
ec2_region_name = eu-west-1
ec2_region_endpoint = ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Location for boto.config:

`/etc/boto.cfg` - for site-wide settings that all users on this machine will use
`~/.boto` - for user-specific settings

Manual: [Boto Config](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html)

Comment: Thanks.  What's the `ec2_version` value for and how do I find out what version is currently in use?

Comment: ec2_version indicates EC2 API version. The version is taken from [EC2 Release Notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Amazon-EC2). I would not worry about it. You can take it out, boto will set reasonable default value.

Answer (score 5):

You can find out which region an EC2 instance is in programmatically like this:

```
import boto.utils
data = boto.utils.get_instance_identity()
region_name = data['document']['region']
```

Once you know the region, you can connect to the correct region in your script like this:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region_name)
```

This should allow your script to be able to run on any instance in any region.

Comment: FYI, `boto.utils.get_instance_identity()` doesn't exist in older versions of boto.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with the following Python code:

```
import boto.utils
m = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()
print m['placement']['availability-zone']
```

Prints `ap-southeast-2b` in my case.